# Google Maps language parameter not working

Tags: google-maps

I have the following code:

```
<img src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=<?php echo $capital['Capital']['name']; ?>&zoom=4&size=400x250&sensor=false&style=feature:administrative.locality|element:labels|visibility:off&language=en&markers=size:small|<?php echo $capital['Capital']['name']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $capital['Capital']['name']; ?>">
```

And the language parameter is not working. The labels are displayed each in their local language. I tried changing the language but with no luck.

Why isn't the map displayed in the language I request? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/staticmaps/#URL_Parameters) says (emphasize mine):

> `language` (optional) defines the language to use for display of labels on map tiles. Note that this parameter is **only supported for some country tiles**; if the specific language requested is not supported for the tile set, then the default language for that tileset will be used.

So could it be that the tiles are not available in English?

Comment: I really doubt myself that countries like Finland or Ukraine don't have an English translation...

Comment: @linkyndy: Works for me with Helsinki and Kiev: http://jsfiddle.net/fkling/rHsLn/... *edit:* but maybe only because my default language is English. I guess I cannot verify it then.

Comment: For each country, in your example, I see: the country's local name and underneath, the English translation. It's the same like in my case. I believe that for English I have to view everything **just** in English, for French, everything just in French and so on...